# How connect to SQL Server Compact 4.0 in ASP.NET?

Tags: sql, asp.net, connection, sql-server-ce

I want connect to SQL Server Compact 4.0 in my ASP.NET application.

Here is example of code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connStr = "Data Source=D:\\MyDB.sdf;";
    string sqlStr = "select * from tblMyTable";

    var sqlDataSrc = new SqlDataSource(connStr, sqlStr);

    GridWithUrls.DataSource = sqlDataSrc;
    GridWithUrls.DataBind();
}
```

But I have the next error:
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

The SqlDataSource has constructor with three parameters, one of them is 'providerName' so, how to specify that I want definitely use Sql Server Compact provider ?
Also I have added System.Data.SqlServerCe reference..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
providerName = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the single database file (e.g. `MySite.sdf`) in the `App_Data` folder.

Add a `connectionStrings` entry to `web.config` to allow connection to the database:

**web.config**:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="db" 
           connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MySite.sdf"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ...
</configuration>
```

And then you can create a connection as desired through the connection string `name` **db**:

```
public static DbConnection CreateConnection()
{
   //Get connection string named "db"
   String csName = "db";
   ConnectionStringSettings cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[csName];
   if (cs == null)
      throw new ConfigurationErrorsException("Could not find connection string \"" + csName + "\"");

   //Get a factory based on the "ProviderName" in the connection string
   DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(cs.ProviderName);
   if (factory == null)
      throw new Exception("Unable to locate factory for " + cs.ProviderName);

   //Have the factory create us a connection object
   DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();

   //Open the connection with the connection string from web.config
   conn.ConnectionString = cs.ConnectionString;
   conn.Open();

   //Give the ready connection to the user
   return conn;
}
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example here:

http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce

If you want to specify the location explicitly try:

```
Data Source=" + (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\MyDB.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the data into a datatable first:

```
        using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(
            Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
        {
            c.Open();

            // Create new DataAdapter
            using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
                "SELECT * FROM tblMyTable", c))
            {

                // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                DataTable t = new DataTable();
                a.Fill(t);

                // Render data onto the screen
                dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
            }
        }
```